# Best practice to store temporary information

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

When my user in the students Role login to the system, he can select various classes that he's enrolled. I already have a filter that'll redirect him to the select class page so he must select a class to access the system, and change it anytime he wants and the whole system's context will change.

As for now, i'm storing IdClass in the session variable, using the code below, and the system uses it to filter all the related queries and functions, like showing all the lessons from the current class. My question is: is this a good practice? Is this right or is there any better and efficient way? I'm trying to follow patterns.

```cs
[Serializable]
public sealed class Session
{
    private const string SESSION_FOO = "STUDYPLATFORM_GUID";

    private Session()
    {
        this.IdClass= 0; // Construct it to 0 so it evaluate as there's no Class selected.
    }

    /* This is the session's public IdClass that
    i can get and set throughout the application. */
    public int IdClass { get; set; }

    public static Session Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_FOO] == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_FOO] = new Session();
            }

            return HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_FOO] as Session;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As for me this class data should be persisted in database so when user access site for example from another pc he still can see classes which he selected before.

Comment: I agree and that is in fact in the backlog, but it's not the question i asked.